# Basic cypher script — ways of exporting dictionary with keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

First off, I'm quite new in Python, so it might not be an elegant piece of code. I apologize for that in advance.
Nevertheless, I wrote two scripts: for cypher and decipher a message. Ciphering works with sampling random prime numbers and assigning printable string signs to those numbers.

*alice.txt* is written message
*bob.txt* is ciphered message
*charlie.txt* is deciphered message
*klucz.txt* is dict with keys

Would be nice to find a way of sending keys not along with message itself. It needs to be saved during ciphering process due to random sampling each time the script is executed.
Cypher code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import string
import json

size = 10 ** 8
cut = size * 0.1
sign_pool = string.printable + '\u0104' + '\u0106' + '\u0118' + '\u0141' + '\u0143' + '\u00D3' + '\u015A' + '\u0179' + '\u017B' + '\u0105' + '\u0107' + '\u0119' + '\u0142' + '\u0144' + '\u00F3' + '\u015B' + '\u017A' + '\u017C'
no_of_signs = len(sign_pool)

start = time.time()


def generate_primes(n):
    is_prime = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)
    is_prime[0:2] = False
    for i in range(int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if is_prime[i]:
            is_prime[i * 2::i] = False
            return np.where(is_prime)[0]


list_with_primes = generate_primes(size)
arr = np.delete(list_with_primes, np.argwhere(list_with_primes <= cut))
arr_lst = arr.tolist()

random_primes = random.sample(arr_lst, no_of_signs)

key_dict = dict(zip(sign_pool, random_primes))
key_coder = dict(zip(random_primes, sign_pool))

with open('klucz.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    json.dump(key_coder, fobj)

fobj.close()

message = []

try:
    with open('alice.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        message = f.read().strip().split()
        f.close()

except:
    print('Plik nie istnieje.')


message_str = ' '.join(map(str, message))
split = [char for char in message_str]
coded_list = []

for index in split:
    coded_list.append(key_dict[index])

try:
    with open('bob.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        for item in coded_list:
            g.write(str(item))
            g.write(' ')
        g.close()

except:
    print('Błąd tworzenia pliku.')


end = time.time()
time_result = round((end - start), 2)
print(str(time_result) + ' s')
```

and decipher:

```
import time 
import json

start = time.time()

with open('klucz.txt', 'r') as fobj:
    d = json.load(fobj)

fobj.close()

message = []

try:
    with open('bob.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        message = f.read().strip().split()
    f.close()

except:
    print('Plik nie istnieje.')


decoded_list = []

for index in message:
    decoded_list.append(d[index])

try:
    with open('charlie.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        for item in decoded_list:
            g.write(str(item))
    g.close()

except:
    print('Błąd tworzenia pliku.')


end = time.time() 
time_result = round((end - start), 2) 
print(str(time_result) + ' s')
```

Comment: for that use Public/Private keys to encrypt the keys that only the receiver can decrypt, but then you don't need these random keys because both users have Public/Private keys

Comment: what is the use of all the `close()` calls? This is just a simple substitution cipher.

Comment: Yes, but the goal was not to recreate RSA. Thanks for the answer, though, it might be the way to do it in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

We don't write BASIC in python

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import string
import json

size = 10 ** 8
cut = size * 0.1
sign_pool = string.printable + '\u0104' + '\u0106' + '\u0118' + '\u0141' + '\u0143' + '\u00D3' + '\u015A' + '\u0179' + '\u017B' + '\u0105' + '\u0107' + '\u0119' + '\u0142' + '\u0144' + '\u00F3' + '\u015B' + '\u017A' + '\u017C'
no_of_signs = len(sign_pool)

start = time.time()


def generate_primes(n):
    is_prime = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)
    is_prime[0:2] = False
    for i in range(int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if is_prime[i]:
            is_prime[i * 2::i] = False
            return np.where(is_prime)[0]


list_with_primes = generate_primes(size)
arr = np.delete(list_with_primes, np.argwhere(list_with_primes <= cut))
arr_lst = arr.tolist()

random_primes = random.sample(arr_lst, no_of_signs)

key_dict = dict(zip(sign_pool, random_primes))
key_coder = dict(zip(random_primes, sign_pool))

with open('klucz.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    json.dump(key_coder, fobj)

message = []

try:
    with open('alice.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        message = f.read().strip().split()
except:
    print('Plik nie istnieje.')

split = [char for char in ' '.join(map(str, message))]

try:
    with open('bob.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        for s in split:
            g.write(str(key_dict[s]))
            g.write(' ')

except:
    print('Błąd tworzenia pliku.')

print(f"{round((time.time() - start), 2)} s")
```

```
import time 
import json

start = time.time()

with open('klucz.txt', 'r') as fobj:
    d = json.load(fobj)

message = []

try:
    with open('bob.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        message = f.read().strip().split()
except:
    print('Plik nie istnieje.')

try:
    with open('charlie.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        for m in message:
            g.write(str(d[m]))
except:
    print('Błąd tworzenia pliku.')

print(f"{round((time.time() - start), 2)} s")
```